# Hash collision rate calculation of 2-choice hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash, probability

For a hash function, I can calculate its collision rate by simple/brute force math calculation:
[image: hash collision probability calculation]

We see that the collision probability of 32-bit hashing is quite high. In order to reduce the collision rate, I'm implementing a variant of [2-choice hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-choice_hashing), which calculates the hash key by two hash functions. I want to know how to calculate the collision probability of my new solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the probability of ANY collision existing?

Comment: A perfect hash function does not have any collisions.

Comment: Per the wiki article that you linked, 2-choice hashing generates two independent hash values, and then only uses one of them. Which means, that after adding N items to the hash table, N of the possible hash values are being used, and the rest are available. When another entry is added, a collision occurs only if both hash functions result in a collision. If the hash functions are independent, the probability that they both have a collision at the same time is the product of the individual probabilities.

Comment: @btilly yes, it's what I mean.

Comment: @tiliavirga question adjusted according to your suggestion.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for your comment, it's a bit counterintuitive. Isn't the second collision test's sample space shrinking after the first collision found?

Comment: @ifree The second comment was wrong. When adding the first entry to the hash table, the probability of success is 1. When adding the second entry, the probability of failure is `F1 = (1/m)^2`, and the resulting probability of success is `1 * (1-F1)`. For the third entry, failure is `F2 = (2/m)^2`, leaving success at `1 * (1-F1) * (1-F2)`. The point at which success is reduced to 50% is approximately 3.4 million entries.

Comment: @user3386109, thanks for the clarification; I do not quite get how you get the 3.4 million entries. Could you please write up for an answer? I'm still figuring it, how about applying Bayes' theorem, which transforms this question into a conditional probability problem

Comment: All I did is write a program that computes the product `1 * (1-F1) * (1-F2) * ... * (1-Fn)`. The program stops when the product falls below 0.5, and then prints `n`. You could also put the equation into your plot, and see the same thing. Just be sure to extend the x-axis out to at least 3.5 million.

Comment: If you're a maths specialist, then I think there's an analysis in the original paper: https://cs.brown.edu/people/eupfal/papers/SICOMP29.pdf A lot of the maths is too squiggly for me to understand, but you may have more luck... It is worth noting that this paper is from 1999, and... correct me if I'm wrong... the method hasn't made its way into mainstream libraries in the last 23 years.

Comment: In real-life applications, though, I would be much more tempted to use a 64-bit hash with a more mainstream hash table implementation.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for your help, I managed to get the answer by some hints you've provided.

Comment: @NeilCoffey Yes, in a real-world application, I'd rather have a stronger hash with proper collision resolution, but I'm just curious so asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think my question falls into a case of general birthday problem `P(k, n, d)` that `k` events collide within `n` trials in sample space `d` where `k` equals 3 and `d` equals 2^32.

I did numerical solving using the equation provided by [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirthdayProblem.html)

```js
Table[NSolve[
  n E^(-n/(
      d k )) - (d^(k - 1) k! Log[1/(1 - p)] (1 - n/(d (k + 1))))^(1/
     k) == 0 /. { p -> 0.5 , k -> i, d -> 2^32}, n, Reals], {i, 2, 4}]
```

The result seems convencible.

```js
{{{n -> 77163.2}}, {{n -> 4.25017*10^6}}, {{n -> 3.39364*10^7}}}
```

I also tried the anwser provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25878/14732) and got a close enough result:

```js
Block[{
  M = 2^32, 
  sampleCount = 8000000, 
  options = Sequence @@ {PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
     GridLines -> {{0.5}},
     MeshFunctions -> {{x, y} |-> y}, Mesh -> {{0.5}}, 
     MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red],
     PlotRange -> {0, 1}}},

   Plot[ 1 - Exp[-Binomial[k, 3]/M^2], {k, 1, sampleCount},
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
    Evaluate @ options ]
 ]
```

[image: 1 - Exp[-Binomial[k, 3]/M^2]]

Comment: The two-choice paradigm does not seem to reduce the number of collisions. Instead, it reduces the consequences of collisions by shortening the maximum length of the lists of colliding items. If that is correct, then the collision rate is the wrong parameter to look at.

Comment: @tiliavirga agreed,  a proper collision resolution is needed indeed.